# Working With Local NuGet Repository

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

We are developing some web applications in our company and all of these web applications reference a library which was developed by our team.

Last week we decided to move our library to a local NuGet Repo to manage versions more easier.

Everything was fine until this morning. Today we wanted to add a new feature to one of our web application and to achieve this we realized that we need to make development at our library that was added to web application project as nuget package, too.

But after adding new codes to library and compile and copy new dll's to web application's bin folder; Visual Studio restore nuget version of dll. (I think Automatic Package Restore causes this)

We don't want to create a new package and publish to local Nuget Repo without being sure code is fine. So now, we are confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the part about "pre-release" versions here:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning

I think you need to

```
1. pre-release (publish) your packages to nuget
2.  have a handful of developers get that package by using the "–IncludePrerelease"
3.  once verified, publish the package (not as "pre-release") version.
```